# Circular reference problem with decorated service

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-dependency-injection

As [the documentation suggests](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#decorating-a-serializer-and-adding-extra-data) I wrote this service to add the uuid to the normalized object:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Serializer;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

final class ApiNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface, SerializerAwareInterface
{
    private DenormalizerInterface|NormalizerInterface $decorated;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        if (!$decorated instanceof DenormalizerInterface) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The decorated normalizer must implement the %s.', DenormalizerInterface::class));
        }

        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        if(method_exists($object, 'getUuid') && is_array($data)){
            $data['uuid'] = $object->getUuid();
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $data
     * @param string $type
     * @param null $format
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format);
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $type, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->decorated->denormalize($data, $type, $format, $context);
    }

    public function setSerializer(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        if($this->decorated instanceof SerializerAwareInterface) {
            $this->decorated->setSerializer($serializer);
        }
    }
}
```

And `services.yaml`

```yaml
App\Serializer\ApiNormalizer:
    # By default .inner is passed as argument
    decorates: 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item'
```

But suddenly (until yesterday everything was fine) it starts to give me this error when I run composer or cache clear

> In CheckCircularReferencesPass.php line 67:
> Circular reference detected for service
> "App\Serializer\ApiNormalizer", path: "App\Serializer\ApiNormalizer ->
> serializer -> App\Serializer\ApiNormalizer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with Symfony Dependency Injection component on version 5.3.7.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42792

This is likely going to be resolved tomorrow or the day after.

On the meantime, just add this to your `composer.json`:

```json
"conflict": {
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "5.3.7"
},
```

This way you can keep the rest of the dependencies updated, and it will just exclude DI 5.3.7 in favour of 5.3.6.

When 5.3.8 is released, you'll be able to update directly.

Comment: It worked thank you very much. I finally found this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42791#issuecomment-908355056